# match and count values in sequence by group in R

Tags: r, match, sequence

Here is my data:

```
group <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4)
X1 <- c("A","A","A","A","B","A","B","A","A","B","B","B","B")
X2 <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","A","A","B","B","A","A")
X3 <- c("B","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
X4 <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B","A","A","A","B","A","B","B")
X5 <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","A","A","A","B","B","B")
X6 <- c("A","A","A","A","B","A","B","A","A","B","B","A","A")
mydf <- data.frame (group, X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6)
```

Thus data is:

```
 group X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1      1  A  A  B  A  A  A
2      1  A  A  A  A  A  A
3      1  A  A  A  A  A  A
4      1  A  A  A  B  A  A
5      2  B  B  B  B  B  B
6      2  A  B  B  B  B  A
7      2  B  B  B  A  B  B
8      3  A  A  B  A  A  A
9      3  A  A  B  A  A  A
10     4  B  B  B  B  A  B
11     4  B  B  B  A  B  B
12     4  B  A  B  B  B  A
13     4  B  A  B  B  B  A
```

Now I need to compare the first row with rest of rows in group.

```
   group X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1      1  A  A  B  A  A  A
2      1  A  A  A  A  A  A
          TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Here mismatch is only at X3. 1 out of 6 = 1/6 = 17%

Similarly compare 3 with 1st in group 1.

```
   group X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1      1  A  A  B  A  A  A
3      1  A  A  A  A  A  A
```

mismatch = 17%

Also compare 4 with 1st in group 1.

```
   group X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1      1  A  A  B  A  A  A
4      1  A  A  A  B  A  A
```

mismatch = 2/6 = 34%

Similarly for group 2 (1st row of group to i.e. 5 with 6)

```
     group X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
5      2  B  B  B  B  B  B
6      2  A  B  B  B  B  A
```

mismatch = 2/6 = 34%

Similarly:

```
         group X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
    5      2  B  B  B  B  B  B
    7      2  B  B  B  A  B  B
```

mismatch = 1/6 = 17%

My trial:

```
match (mydf[1,], mydf[2,])
match (mydf[1,], mydf[3,])
```

Comment: Can you please give your exact expected output, including the data structure?

Comment: Does every row in the same group get the same score?

Comment: @josilber first row is compared with 2 and yield mismatch percent, then first row is compared with 3 and yield mismatch and so on. The idea is the first row in each group works as templete

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
match_ratio <- function(x)
   cbind(x, match_ratio = rowMeans(mapply(`==`, x[1, -1], x[, -1])))
library(plyr)
ddply(mydf, "group", match_ratio)

#    group X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 match_ratio
# 1      1  A  A  B  A  A  A   1.0000000
# 2      1  A  A  A  A  A  A   0.8333333
# 3      1  A  A  A  A  A  A   0.8333333
# 4      1  A  A  A  B  A  A   0.6666667
# 5      2  B  B  B  B  B  B   1.0000000
# 6      2  A  B  B  B  B  A   0.6666667
# 7      2  B  B  B  A  B  B   0.8333333
# 8      3  A  A  B  A  A  A   1.0000000
# 9      3  A  A  B  A  A  A   1.0000000
# 10     4  B  B  B  B  A  B   1.0000000
# 11     4  B  B  B  A  B  B   0.6666667
# 12     4  B  A  B  B  B  A   0.5000000
# 13     4  B  A  B  B  B  A   0.5000000
```

Comment: Nice! `ddply` is powerful. My solution is much more raw.

Answer (score 2):

```
## generate pairs of row numbers
rows <- sequence(nrow(mydf))
grid <- subset(expand.grid(Var1=rows,Var2=rows),Var1 > Var2)

## define some functions
comparison1 <- function(a,b,x)
  match(x[a,-1],x[b,-1])

comparison2 <- function(a,b,x)
  x[a,-1]==x[b,-1]

## apply (comparison1 or comparison2)
matches <- t(mapply(comparison1,grid$Var2,grid$Var1,MoreArgs=list(x=mydf)))
dimnames(matches) <- list(paste(grid$Var2,grid$Var1,sep=","),
                          names(mydf)[-1])
```

If you use `comparison1`

```
> head(matches)
    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1,2  1  1 NA  1  1  1
1,3  1  1 NA  1  1  1
1,4  1  1  4  1  1  1
1,5 NA NA  1 NA NA NA
1,6  1  1  2  1  1  1
1,7  4  4  1  4  4  4
```

If you use `comparison2`

```
> head(matches)
       X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6
1,2  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
1,3  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
1,4  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
1,5 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
1,6  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
1,7 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

The row names correspond to the pair of row numbers you are comparing.